# How to pass class name as parameter and then automatic using it to create object in C#?

Tags: c#

For example, I have a class name `User`:

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dod { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have a method to create new Object:

```
    public static object CreateObject(input)
    {
         --create new object with input as class name--
    }
```

When I pass 'User' as input to CreateObject, it return an UserObject
or anyway to convert a string to a class name

Comment: Why do you need to do this? How would you use it after you created it? Why can't you use `Type`? There's almost certainly a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I use it to flexibly recognize unknown data. I have a method to automatic generate a new class from data, but don't know how to use this class to automatic create object then

Comment: Use the object's `Type` and maintain a lookup.

Comment: Or you can use the generic form `static void Test<T>(T t) where T:class`

Comment: is it the best way? I use it like this `Type type = Type.GetType("User");` and got `type` as `User`, but is it possible to use this `type` to get db data: `type data = getDataFromDB();`

Comment: @ghs I don't know exactly what you want to do

Comment: Remember that C# is strongly typed, but hey , `static T getDataFromDB<T>() where T : class, new() => new T()`,  `var data = getDataFromDB<user>();`

Comment: If you have enough data about the class to be constructed, you might be able to use [Activator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=net-6.0)